# Post action that would display a new HTML based overlay, darkening the background?

Tags: html, css, forms, post, overlay

I want to create a button with a POST action;
Once the user clicks the button, an overlaying layer would appear at the center of the screen, darkening the rest of it;
that layer should contain some HTML code (such as a tracking snippet) and therefore its code cannot be in the original page.

Any clue how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You need Javascript to do this, the keyword you're looking for is `modal` or `lightbox`, see https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ for an example.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can be done without any Javascript, and if so, would rather use regular CSS.

Comment: Click events require Js/JQ...not much you can do about that. Also CSS can't style what isn't on the page.

Comment: [I've opened a new qestion with an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860820/how-does-this-button-work-cant-find-the-class-definiton-in-the-css)